# Detect orphan jars in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, orphan

Is there any modern tool to detect unused jars in an eclipse project? The last release of [ClassPath Helper](http://classpathhelper.sourceforge.net/) is in 2008 and it does not works properly for me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012298/how-can-i-identify-unnecessary-jars-included-in-my-project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did is delete the repository and let Maven rebuild it, like that I could handle the jars in a easiest way.