# Eclipse find which files reference this jar

Tags: java, eclipse

We have a lot of jars which have been added over a period of years to the project and their usage has not been documented anywhere. I want to figure out references of any class in the jar in java or jsp files.

Now for our new jars we don't have this issue as we use Maven and it helps us maintain dependency etc much better. But I am trying to determine some of the old jars

Is there any way in Eclipse, or any other tool, to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding unused jars used in an eclipse project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/248589/finding-unused-jars-used-in-an-eclipse-project)

Comment: Yeah you are right.. This is a duplicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way which I can think of:

1. You can use [Relief](http://www.workingfrog.org/) to get a view of your whole java project. I haven't used it though, but have heard good things about it.

**Update:**

[Finding unused jars used in an eclipse project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248589/finding-unused-jars-used-in-an-eclipse-project)

Comment: answer updated, the first point didn't really answer your question.

Comment: That "Relief" link doesn't seem to go to anything at all related. Did a squatter grab the domain?

Comment: looks like the project disappeared from the internet. I found this article which mentions that and many other related projects: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/10/java-code-quality-tools-overview.html