# find unused jar in project

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, classpath

I have large project that have many unused jars in it, I want to remove that jars. I can't do it manually. How to find jars that are not used by project. I have tried `classpathhelper` but its not worthy for me, any other suggestion. I'm using eclipse.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/248589/finding-unused-jars-used-in-an-eclipse-project

Comment: @WhiteFang34 -i have already gone through that, but not worked for me as my application is too large about 500 jars and 3500 classes, i can not surf individual jar due to its more time consuming, thats why i asked for any other sugestion

Answer (score 0):

Could you get Classpath Helper to work for you by increasing heap size of your Eclipse? See "Note Regarding Eclipse" on http://classpathhelper.sourceforge.net/.

Comment: no memory problem, i have disclosed 500 jars to say i can not emphasize  individual jar due to big no.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've said that the [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248589/finding-unused-jars-used-in-an-eclipse-project) isn't sufficient I'll offer a fairly odd idea to consider. It's not trivial, however neither is your problem if you have 500 jars. You could try using [ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/) on your application. You'll have to configure it to be aware of all entry points (main methods or servlets, etc), see their [examples](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#/manual/examples.html).

It can generate a single jar output that contains only the necessary classes from all of your dependency jars. From that you could cross reference every remaining class in that jar for which dependency jars you actually need. I'm not suggesting that you use the output from ProGuard, simply that you use it for filtering. You'd have to write a script or program to do this though. As I said, non-trivial :)

Comment: Does ProGuard deal with dynamically loaded classes? Most modern frameworks use dynamic class loading extensively, which makes dependency tracking quite difficult.

Comment: @thkala: it handles some cases like `Class.forName()` (see [FAQ](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#/FAQ.html)). It's not going to catch all possibilities though, so you have to configure it to know about the ones it can't find. With a modern dynamic class loading framework it probably won't work very well. You'd probably need something to enumerate all of the possible classes so you could add it to the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this, hope it helps!

[JarAnalyzer](http://www.kirkk.com/main/Main/JarAnalyzer)