# How can I figure out which of the 200 linked JARs, my Eclispe project actually needs?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, buildpath

I am currently working in an very old Java Eclipse project which has a lot of JARs linked to it's build path.

I have noticed that several of them aren't being used by the project any more, meaning old libraries that has been forgotten when the code has evolved over the years.

A standard way to determine if the library is used, is to simply remove it and see if there are any compilation errors.

However, I have noticed that some libraries in the build path are invoked by reflection, meaning if I remove the library I won't get any compilation errors. But the project will crash due to not finding the code anymore. Problem is you don't know when that can happen.

**Is there a tool I can use to figure out which of all the linked JAR libraries I can safely remove, without getting compilation or reflection errors?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding unused jars used in an eclipse project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/248589/finding-unused-jars-used-in-an-eclipse-project)

Comment: Be very careful.  Unless you inspect all the code you cannot locate all the reflection points, and the application may crash a long time after being invoked because some rare code is being executed.

Comment: That's my biggest fear and I am hoping there is a clever tool that can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [ClassPathHelper](http://classpathhelper.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: No, and I don't think it's even theoretically possible using a static code analyzer.