# Finding unused libraries in java web application

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I have more than 200 libraries in my java web application due to which it takes much time to built and slow performance.
do we have any tool or cmd for finding such unused libraries other than manual search from eclipse ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding unused jars used in an eclipse project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/248589/finding-unused-jars-used-in-an-eclipse-project)

Comment: Do you *know* your 200 libraries are the major contributer to slow build times ?

Comment: if you are not using a library,then why that libraries are in your classpath. remove the unwanted jars.

Comment: @KalaiarasanManimaran I partially agree with your comment because at first I have to find unused ones which is checked-in by other developers.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen unused is which do not have any reference in project.

Comment: @BrianAgnew yes I know that why I wanted to remove

Comment: Note that this is harder when you have web applications because your JSP files (or equivalent technology) may be the only referrer of a given class. i would personally not trust a tool but instead bite the bullet and handle this manually.  If you do not have a test suite in place, this is a great opportunity.

Comment: I am fully agree with you @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen regarding jsp files. did you mean that best way manual search like : search a package contain in jar in all files.

Comment: remove, run tests to see if works, repeat with next

Answer (score 3):

Add a JVM parameter -verbose:class to your server. This will  log the jar files from which each class is loaded.

Deploy your web application and do a full test (to capture the classes that are loaded dynamically).

Capture the logs for individual jar files.

Remove the jar files that are not listed in the above step

Or you can use pom.xml with maven-dependency-plugin and find the unused jars.

Comment: I agree it will help for java classes, but what about jsp and other files which may or may not have references. will it work for these files also?

Comment: For jsp , if the above solution didn't help you, you need to brute force only. i don't think there will be option.