# How to rectify all valid libs in a java project?

Tags: java, eclipse, libs

I am migrating a java project into a Maven project , so i have to check/validate all listed libs to figure out the uses ones.I mean i have to exclude the not using libraries (jar files).

So i figured out the one way is to go in .classpath file and comment each classpathentry and build and see if that is being used.And it is very tedious job :)
Think about when you have a 20 year old product and with 200+ libs.

Please suggest some automate ways to do this in a single go.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding unused jars used in an eclipse project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248589/finding-unused-jars-used-in-an-eclipse-project)

Comment: Thanks @dnault for the comment , though accepted answer is not helpful but i got the right answer.

Comment: Glad to hear you solved the problem! If you want, you can help others by posting an answer to your own question.

Comment: i just simply converted my code to Maven project and used the **mvn dependencies:analyze** , though it is not fully reliable until you know all its flag and and tricks